# Exclude src/main/resources from classpath when running tests

Tags: java, gradle, junit, hbase

I have a local integration test that uses the `HBaseTestingUtility` to create a local HBase test environment. Starting it with its default configuration is as simple as:

```
HBaseTestingUtility hbaseUtility = new HBaseTestingUtility();
hbaseUtility.startMiniCluster();
```

and then I have several JUnit tests that interact with HBase.

However, if my `src/main/resources` folder contains `hbase-site.xml` then the HBase instance will pull in Kerberos configuration from there, try to connect to a remote HBase instance, and die. I don't understand why this happens - I thought that only `src/test/resources` files were available when running tests?

How can I exclude `src/main/resources` from the classpath when running these tests?

If it helps, my build tool is Gradle, and there's no configuration in it that would tell tests to read from `src/main/resources`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately your tests will be testing everything which gets included in the jar/war produced by the project. This includes compiled classes and resources. So it makes perfect sense to me that `src/main/resources` are on the test classpath.

Rather than excluding specific files from `src/main/resources` I suggest that you move `hbase-site.xml` from `src/main/resources` to `src/non-test/resources` or similar. You could then include this folder in the jar but leave it out of the test classpath

Answer (score 0):

A workaround for this specific situation (using `HBaseTestingUtility`) is to create blank files for each of the Hadoop XML files that exist in `src/main/resources`. In my case, I added the following files to `src/test/resources`:

- core-site.xml
- hbase-site.xml
- hdfs-site.xml

Each containing:

```
<configuration>
</configuration>
```

The blank files take precedence over those in `src/main/resources`, and the `HBaseTestingUtility` works as expected.

Comment: Possibly a better solution is to look for `${env}-core-site.xml`, `${env}-hbase-site.xml` etc where ${env} is a system property. You could then have different config files for test, UAT and prod etc each with unique filenames which don't rely on classpath ordering

Comment: Yes I guess that once we move towards production then having multiple environments will sort this out.